# C++ and Selenium IDE not fast enough

Tags: c++, browser, automation, selenium-ide

I have a game that I'm trying to automate. The game works like this: there are some lightbulbs on the screen and only one of them is lit. When you press it another one lights up. If you press the wrong bulb you get penalised 5 seconds and in total there are 60 seconds.

I managed to score 90 points on a phone. However i would like to get over 150 or at least come close.

So i've written this C++ program but it only gets about 85 points.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
#include"windows.h"

using namespace std;

inline bool if_yell(HDC &dc, int x, int y){
    COLORREF color = GetPixel(dc, x, y);
    if( (int)GetRValue(color)==251 && (int)GetGValue(color)==190 && 
(int)GetBValue(color)==43)return 1;
    return 0;
}

 int px[]={327,1014,508,849,332,1014,331,1015,501,849,670,676,564,689},py[]={214,214,385,386,558,558,903,901,731,730,561,904,657,891};

int main()
{
    HDC dc = GetDC(NULL);
    POINT _cursor;
    COLORREF color;
    int ls=-1;
    while(1){
        for(int i=0;i<14;++i){
            if(if_yell(dc,px[i],py[i]) && ls!=i){
                    INPUT Inputs[3] = {0};

                    Inputs[0].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
                    Inputs[0].mi.dx = px[i]*34; // desired X coordinate
                    Inputs[0].mi.dy = py[i]*61; // desired Y coordinate
                    Inputs[0].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;

                    Inputs[1].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
                    Inputs[1].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;

                    Inputs[2].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
                    Inputs[2].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;

                    SendInput(3, Inputs, sizeof(INPUT));
                    ls=i;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then I tried to use Selenium IDE. I recorded myself playing and this is what resulted. I added more identical commands and ran it.

It's quite fast. It scores about 102 points, but I would like to get an even better result if it's possible. Please help me.

[image]

I also thought about using AutoHotKey. After implementing something similar to the C++ code I found its performance to be quite mediocre. But maybe writing a script for each lightbulb in order to make it faster would help. I tried running the Selenium script on both a Linux and a Windows computer but without any succes.

Edit: You would think that C++ would press the button almost instantaneously, but it doesn't. So where could the delay come from ?